# How can i redirect my node application to domain.com using htaccess

Tags: node.js, .htaccess

My project runs on domain.com:4200. How can I get it to work on domain.com using a rewrite rule.
Tried this but this is not working

```
RewriteRule
^ "\ http: \ / \ / 127.0.0.1 \:% (4200) REQUEST_URI" [P, QSA, L]
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for showing your efforts. Could you please do mention from which url to which url you want to redirect? Kindly do mention the same in your question in CODE TAGS.